# How to to load a URL at specific time intervals in a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

How do I load a specified URL in Greasemonkey, every 15 minutes? The problem is that a page redirects me to another URL. I want to automatically return to my specified URL every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, just use the following script in greasemonkey,

```
window.setTimeout(main,10000);

function main()
{
  window.location.replace("http://google.com");
}
```